# Opening outlook window with html table in E-Mail body

Tags: outlook, html-table, html-email

There is a requirement to open a outlook screen on click of the button/link. This opened outlook window should have a pre-filled message body text which is in tabular format.

There are various solutions on Stack Overflow which open outlook window with E-Mail Body in plain text format. Unfortunately we could not find any solution where the outlook window opens the Mail Body in HTML format (for e.g. HTML Table).

Comment: How would you do this in plain html (not a outlook content but from a plain html page)? Find a solution for that and you'll have the JSF counterpart. Effectively this is not a PF or JSF problem. Edited tags to increase your chance of an answer

Comment: Im pretty sure this is not possible, since you can only make a text mail from a link click in a mail.